# Phpunit, how to emulate events connected to a time, periods?

Tags: php, phpunit

Lets suppose I have a database record:

```
| ID | GAME_NAME | CREATED  | TIMETOLIVEINSECONDS
  1      game1     11:11:00           40
  2      game2     11:11:00           50
  3      game3     11:11:00           60
  4      game4     11:11:00           70
```

suppose the time is `11:11:30` right now, the games live for `10`, `20`, `30`, `40` seconds, when this time have passed, an automatic algorithm deletes the records. So I have to make sure those games will actually be gone, my question is, how to emulate it somehow in a test? I dont think with a well-planned `sleep()` function :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class that will provide the current time. Basically is a wrapper for a time() sentence.

Then, on the tests, you can mock the class or create a subclass that will work as needed.

On the real code, you must have the class passed as an argument, or created via a ServiceFactory, or use any other method that allows you to set the time provider class from the test.

---

If you opt for the subclass, here you have an example. Suppose you have a TimeProvider class with a getCurrentTimestamp method:

In the tests, you would use this subclass:

```
class ConfigurableTimeProvider extends \libraries\time\TimeProvider
{
    private $current_timestamp = null;

    public function getCurrentTimestamp()
    {
        if (!$this->current_timestamp) {
            $this->current_timestamp = parent::getCurrentTimestamp();
        }
        return $this->current_timestamp;
    }

    public function setCurrentTimestamp($timestamp)
    {
        $this->current_timestamp = $timestamp;
    }

    public function applyOffset($offset)
    {
        $this->setCurrentTimestamp($this->getCurrentTimestamp() + $offset);
    }
}
```

The applyOffset is specially useful for the kind of tests you need as it allows to simulate that time passes so the tests become very clear.